# Mod Rewrite not working on my addon domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a Wordpress website on my main domain. For the Wordpress website, I have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I just created an addon domain and wanted to use new rules for it. I created a `.htaccess` file and put it inside the addon folder, eg. `/newaddon`.

In the `.htaccess` file I have:

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^readjob/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ readjob.php?id=$1&amp;cat=$2&amp;title=$3
</IfModule>
```

The URL stucture I have is this:

http://www.website.com/readjob/3/jobs/web-designers-potech-integrated-services/

But it keeps telling me that the link is broken. I don't know what to do, please I need assistance. I just learnt mod rewriting today, so clarity will be highly appreciated.

Comment: My bet is it's a problem with your RewriteBase. However, please provide more details on readjob.php - which directory is it in relative to WordPress and newaddon/

Comment: the readjob.php is a file inside the newaddon folder. ie. www.newaddon.com/readjob.php

Comment: Love the RESTful URL structure there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what your looking for:

**Options -Multiviews**

I use this in my root directory of domains hosted under my main domain and in my case they happen to be two levels deep.

i.e.

Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

to clarify you add **Options -Multiviews** to the addon websites htaccess file. :D

Comment: u are just an angel... it worked the page got displayed, bt the page couldnt access my css and pics anylonger. i hv my css in a folder inside the addon domain /css and pictures inside /pics. Pls wht do u think is the prob, thank you so much

Comment: It seems as if it changes the directory structure cos when i click on link on the page it appears this way: http://www.myaddonwebsite.com/readjob/2/jobs/business-officer-eden-solutions-and-resources-ltd/index.php

Comment: Hmm, Nitrix pls , i thought i solved the problem using the base tag, but now it affects all absolute links to external websites on the page, ow do i fix it

Comment: How exactly is it affecting the absolute links to external websites?

Answer (score 0):

This is not HTML where the `&` should be represented with a character reference (except if used as a reference open delimiter). So:

```
RewriteRule ^readjob/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ readjob.php?id=$1&cat=$2&title=$3
```

Furthermore, you should use a more specific pattern than `.*` like `[^/]+`:

```
RewriteRule ^readjob/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ readjob.php?id=$1&cat=$2&title=$3
```

Comment: Gumbo, i did exactly what u said , i changed the rewriterule , it started displaying error 404 (im sure readjob.php is on server). when i remove the RewriteBase line the error changed "Oops the link is broken". Pls any clue?

Comment: @Ogugua Belonwu: Are you using both .htaccess files on the same domain only in different folders (i.e. `/` and `/newaddon/`)?

Comment: Let me illustrate what i have: i have the main website: www.main.com, i have a .htacess file for the main website that works, inside the www.main.com folder i create another folder which houses an addon domain (www.addon.com) and put another .htaccess file in it to handle its modrewrite. This is the .htaccess that gives the problem. Hope is clearer, thanks

Comment: @Ogugua Belonwu: Well, the rule in the .htaccess file in `/` is applied on all requests (as .htaccess is a per-directory configuration file). You can restrict that rule only on requests to *www.main.example* by adding this condition: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.main.example`.

Comment: @Ogugua Belonwu: Well, since that condition is only fulfilled if the host is *www.main.example*, I guess you rather want it in the .htaccess file for that domain.

Comment: Pls i put the line in the main website folder, i started the page nt found, pls these are two diff rewrite rules, i actually dnt have anything to do with the one in the main website, what im interested in is the htaccess in the addon domain folder, pls my head is goin bananas and boss is on my head

Comment: @Ogugua Belonwu: I’m not quite sure in what order the .htaccess files are processed and depending on the configuration it might even be possible that .htaccess files in directories other than the document root directory are not even taken into account. So if you don’t have access to the .htaccess file in the document root directory, I guess you have no chance to get your rules working correctly.

Comment: 1st .htaccess file in / folder ; 2nd .htaccess file is in /myaddon folder . pls i did nt mean i cannot modify the 1st .htaccess in / , i mean its working well for main website. my prob is the .htaccess in /myaddonfolder

Comment: @Ogugua Belonwu: I did understand you. But to determine whether .htaccess files in directories other than the document root directory are processed, you need to add the mentioned condition to have that rule only applied on that main host name and not the other domain.

Comment: i did add it and the main website stopped rewriting properly

Comment: i did add RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mainwebsitename.com to d .htaccess in / folder